# Refer to key in value when creating object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any syntax to do something like the following

```
var obj = {a: this, b: this}
```

and get

```
obj = {a: 'a', b: 'b'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an object that has a bunch of keys and values equaling the same string, it's as simple as:

```
var obj = {};
['a','b'].forEach(function(item) {
    obj[item] = item;
});
```

Comment: I like this solution, even though I was wondering if it was possible on object creation

Comment: By the way, in node, where I'm using this, you need to initialize the array before using forEach.

Comment: @ykay - Are you sure? I just tried typing `['a','b','c'].forEach(function(c) { Console.log(c); });` into node.js. It worked.

Comment: Hi Andrew, you're right, express was throwing an error if I started a line with the array but the line before wasn't closed with a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var obj = {a: "this is A", b: "this is B"}
obj.a equals to "this is A"
obj.b equals to "this is B"
```

A quick snippet using this object example to add the pointer locations stored in an object:

```js
function getMousePosition(event){

var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
mouse.x = event.clientX;
mouse.y = event.clientY;

Elem = document.getElementById("Elem");

Elem.innerHTML = "Simple Mouse Position by Khriztian Azuaje.<br><br>" + "X pos: " + mouse.x + ", Y pos: " + mouse.y;
}
```

```css
#Elem {
  background:black;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  padding:2px;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:160px;
}
```

```html
<body onmousemove="getMousePosition(event)">
<div id="Elem"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It might help to explain a bit about why your code works.

Comment: Why would you go to the trouble of initializing `obj` to `{a: this, b: this}`? Writing `var obj = {}` would give you identical results in the end

Comment: @SuperBiasdMan He asked for a syntax, not how objects work. I rest assured giving a simple object syntax without explanation knowing its what he's after (in a simple way).

Comment: I'll edit my answer to avoid unnecessary missunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I'm not sure why you would use but here it is:

```
var obj = { a: 'you', b: 'they'};
var newObj = {};

for (var key in obj) { 
    newObj[key] = key
};

//newObj = {a: "a", b: "b"}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems pretty good, but I was wondering if I could do this on the object creation